# Remove end character in a textbox without rewriting all the data

Tags: vb.net, serial-communication

I am writing a program to communicate over the serial port.  All data that is sent is mirrored back.  Everything works fine except backspaces.  When I hit the backspace button the only way I know how to remove the last character in the text box is to use a mid function then overwrite the current data with the new data.  When a lot of data is inside the richtextbox it starts to flicker.  I have tried using the richtextbox.text.remove function but I get this error.  "Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count"

```
RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(RichTextBox1.TextLength, 1)
```

I have tried to throw some number into the function that does not cause it to error out but no data is removed from the richtextbox.

Here is the code that transmits data

```
   KeyCharString = e.KeyChar 'stores key being pressed into KeyCharString
    Try
        SerialPort1.Write(KeyCharString) 'tx data for key being pressed
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message) 'Displays error if serialport1 cannot be written to
    End Try

    If Asc(KeyCharString) = 8 Then 'If char is a backspace remove precious character and exit sub
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(RichTextBox1.TextLength, 1)
        'RichTextBox1.Text = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, 1, RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1)'Old code used to remove the character.  Causes the richtextbox to flicker when rewriting the data
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This is the code that receives data

```
    receivedString = SerialPort1.ReadExisting.ToString

    If Asc(receivedString) = 8 Then 'deletes the received data if it is a backspace
        receivedString = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(receivedString) 'adds new data to the richtextbox
```

Is there a way to remove 1 character from the richtextbox without rewriting all the data inside it?  Also, the richtextbox is read only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc) method that you are using returns a String it does not do anything with the original string.

from MSDN Link:

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted.

Try this but I am not sure of the flicker:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1, 1)
```

or something like this:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1
RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1
RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = False
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = ""
RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = True
```

Comment: Mark, I completely missed the assignment in my solution so I deleted it.  Your second option is the way to go.

Comment: The second code just highlights the character that would be removed and does not delete it.  The first code removes it but causes a flicker.

Comment: @LaggMaster it is working properly on my computer, are you setting the SelectedText to ""

Comment: I am setting the SelectedText to "".  When I load the debugger and step through the code it does not set the selected text to "".  I tried to force the selectedText to "" in the watch menu and when I hit enter it sets it back to the old character.

Comment: @LaggMaster I see what is going on, it is the Readonly Property see my edit.

Comment: I figured setting the read only to false then true would cause a flicker but it does not.  Something odd, if i set the selected text to " " it would replace the existing character but would cause the string length to be the same.  So you can only delete 1 character.  The code new works, Thank you.